# shopt -s cdable_vars is not expanding as expected

Tags: bash, shell, shopt

In my cluster (I don't have root access of it), I have defined in my `.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
shopt -s direxpand
export s13=/c13scratch/rudrab
```

I am the owner of the `/c13scratch/rudrab`:

```
ll /c13scratch/ |\grep rudrab
drwxr-xr-x 15 rudrab         users 4.0K Apr 29 23:58 rudrab
```

Now, I am facing the following situations:

1. `cd s1<tab>` or `cd s13<tab>`:  Nothing happens.
2. `cd $s13<tab>` gives: `cd $s13<space>`
3. After 2,  if I use `<backspace>` in `cd $s13<space>`, then it is expanded to `cd /c13scratch/rudrab` and subsequent tabs are showing subdirs inside `/c13scratch/rudrab`

I am expecting `cd s13<tab>`(without `$` sign) to complete my normal `bash_completion`, and show me the subdirs.

What I am doing wrong here?

I am using:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution (variable name will get expanded, but its value won't be substituted into command line): if you have `bash-completion` package installed, reinstall completion for `cd` command:

```
complete -v -F _cd -o nospace cd pushd
```

The package does this if `cdable_vars` is set when `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` is sourced, so you might want to install a profile.d that will get sourced before it.

If you don't have the package, `info bash` gives an example of completion function for `cd` that supports `cdable_vars`.